# iterative definition of object properties

Tags: matlab, object, struct

Say you have an object `A` with property `B`
and you want to define some parameters
of `A.B` (say `A.B.n1 , A.B.n2 , ....` ) since these parameters are many you would like to do this iteratively. The problem I have is
that whenever i try to do it in an iteratively manner:

```
for j=1:4
    S=strcat('n',int2str(j));
    A.B.S=j;
end
```

I only define `A.B.S=4` and do not create 
`A.B.n1=1 , A.B.n2=2,...,A.B.n4=4`.

How is it possible to make MATLAB understand that I want `S` to be a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-38.html#br1v5cc-1) to access the structure data:

```
S = strtrim(cellstr(num2str((1:10)','n%d')));   %#'
for i=1:numel(S)
    A.B.(S{i}) = i;
end
```

The result

```
>> A.B
ans = 
     n1: 1
     n2: 2
     n3: 3
     n4: 4
     n5: 5
     n6: 6
     n7: 7
     n8: 8
     n9: 9
    n10: 10
```